# What is res.locals and where are we getting it from?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is my first question here :-)

**I want to know more about res.locals.**

**The official documentation says:**

> An object that contains response local variables scoped to the request, and therefore available only to the view(s) rendered during that request/response cycle (if any).

1. **What do they mean by "scoped to the
   request"?**

I know we can access response local variables in EJS this way:

```
<title> <%= locals.title %> </title>
```

**2. How we are able to access this in the views? From where we are getting this property?**

Any help will be much-appreciated :p.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using EJS perhaps?

Comment: yes I'm using EJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. What do they mean by "scoped to the request"?

Since `res.locals` is a `locals` property on the `res` object, it is by nature only scoped to the current `res` object which is only available to the specific request being processed.  Thus, it is data that is only available to those processing the current request and each request has it's own copy of the `res.locals` object with its own values.

Note, the opposite of "scoped to the request" would be assigning properties to a global object that are available to all request handlers, regardless of which request it is.

> 2. How we are able to access this in the views? From where we are getting this property?

When a template engine is processing a view, it is passed the `res` object from which it can access `res.locals` and it is a convention used by most template engines that they will look in `res.locals` to resolve variables present in the template (if they match property names on the `res.locals` object and if those property names are not otherwise passed on the object send with `res.render()`).  In other words, `res.locals` is in the search path for template engines to resolve variables mentioned in a template.

Comment: Thanks a lot! What is the difference between locals(in view) and res.locals? Are both the same objects?

Comment: @ShivamSingh - `locals` in the view depends upon the template engine as to whether you just use the property name by itself and the template engine automatically looks in `res.locals` for that property name or whether you specify `locals.somePropertyName` in the template.  You don't reference `res.locals` from within the template.   That's how your code in the request handler (not in the template) sets things into the locals so they can later by used in the template.